# How to handle malicious URL's (xyz.com/*)

Tags: asp.net, url, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET 4.5 MVC 4 Application. I want to redirect xyz.com/* and malicious URL's with illegal characters to custom errors page. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they put in an invalid route like your example you could set your custom errors something like this

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"  defaultRedirect="~/error">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/error/Error404" />
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/error" />
</customErrors>
```